# Can a seperate thread continue execution on an object synchronised by another?

Tags: java, multithreading

Say I have an object A which has 2 methods:

```
public doSomething()
{....}

public synchronised doSomethingElse()
{ ... }
```

and I have `thread1.doSomethingElse()`, will it still be possible for `thread2.doSomething()` to execute or is it blocked by thread1's lock?

If so, how can I make thread1 execute at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of synchronization 
1. Object level 
2. Class level (Class level synchronization is for the static methods only.)

In your case since your methods are not static it is object level synchronization. For object level synchronization you can either synchronize your whole methods or you can synchronize some block of your methods.

When you synchronized one method. Its mean that same object of your class cant access your synchronized method from different threads. As each object have only one lock. If you had called doSomethingElse() for same obj but from different threads. Then It will be accessible by one thread.

**Now comes to your answer:**
As your first method is not synchronized i.e something(). It will not be effected in any case if you call it for any no of threads or even call it when your first thread is currently in the method. **Locks are only for synchronized methods**

```
Yourclass obj = new Yourclass();
Thread A = new MyThread(obj);
Thread B =  new MyThread(obj);
```

......

```
public void run()
{
  \\do what ever you want
   \\both of your methods will be called.
   \\ call them both here.
}
```

here i have made objects of same Mythread class you can do as per you want. you can make objects of two different implemented thread classes and write your run. **In any case it will have no effect on the call.**

Answer (score 0):

Since thread 2 is not attempting to acquire any lock, it is not blocked and can run concurrently with thread 1. There's nothing special you need to do.

Comment: Ah ok...a senior developer at a big bank told me as part of an interview that thread1 will be acquiring a lock for the whole object in that synchronised block, therefore thread2 won't be able to execute, something which confused the hell out of me...am I misunderstanding something or was he just wrong?

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine You either don't remember correctly, misunderstood him or he's a moron.

Comment: Thread 1 will acquire the lock on the object. But thread 2 doesn't attempt to acquire that lock. So thread 2 is able to execute. Locks don't know what they lock. They work on the honor system.